# Perl extracting lines from .zip/.gz file

Tags: perl, compression, extract

I have one very large file that is compressed (.zip or .gz). I want to save time and space by NOT decompressing that very large (1TB) file. It's a single file, so no directories to worry about. I basically want to mimic:

```
open(FH,"<$file_name");  

while(chomp($line = <FH>)){  ... }
```

Is that possible? If yes, how?
Thanks much
Mike

Comment: Unix has `gzip -dc` which will decompress and stream. I'd be stunned to find there wasn't a perl module, but even if there isn't, you could open that as an exec pipe.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is - gzip can 'cat' to stdout. Sometimes you have `gzcat` but more commonly `gzip -dc <filename>`.

So you could do it like this:

```
open ( my $gunzip_stream, "-|", "gzip -dc $gzip_file" or die $!;
while ( <$gunzip_stream> ) {
     print;
}
```

A quick google suggests [`IO::Compress::Gunzip`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Gunzip.html)  might do the trick too.

> If you are running Perl 5.005 or better the object, $z , returned from IO::Uncompress::Gunzip can be used exactly like an IO::File filehandle. This means that all normal input file operations can be carried out with $z . For example, to read a line from a compressed file/buffer you can use either of these forms

```
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip;
my $z = new IO::Uncompress::Gunzip $input [OPTS]
        or die "IO::Uncompress::Gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";
```

And either:

```
$line = $z->getline();
$line = <$z>;
```

For zip files it's a bit harder. You can use [`Archive::Zip`](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Archive-Zip-1.45/lib/Archive/Zip.pm) but zip files can have multiple members. Even so:

```
# Read a Zip file
my $somezip = Archive::Zip->new();
unless ( $somezip->read( 'someZip.zip' ) == AZ_OK ) {
    die 'read error';
}

foreach my $member ( $somezip -> members() ) { 
   print $member -> content();
}
```

I don't *think* it works as well for line by line streaming though. (This may be a limitation of the compression method. I'm not entirely sure).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the [`Archive::Zip::MemberRead`](https://metacpan.org/module/Archive::Zip::MemberRead) module.

You don't say much about what you want to do, but it looks roughly like the code below. `$zip_fh` isn't a real file handle—just an object that has methods that make it look like one—so you can't read from it using `<$zip_fh>`.

Also, `getline` returns each line with the line terminator stripped from the end, so there's no need for a `chomp`. If you're reading files that have been written on a platform with a different standard line ending then you may have to mess with something such as

```
Archive::Zip::MemberRead->setLineEnd("\r\n")
```

but normally you can just forget about it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip;
use Archive::Zip::MemberRead;

my $zip_file = 'myfile.zip';

my $zip    = Archive::Zip->new($zip_file) or die $!;
my $member = $zip->memberNamed('path/to/item.txt');
my $zip_fh = $member->readFileHandle;

while ( defined( my $line = $zip_fh->getline ) ) {
  print $line, "\n";
}
```